# multiple django urls arguments not working

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.gallery, name='home'),
url(r'^(?P<album_id>\d+)/(?P<pic_id>\d+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
url(r'^(?P<album_id>\d+)/', views.album_details, name='album_details'),
]
```

views.py

```
def details(request, pic_id):

picture = get_object_or_404(Picture, pk=pic_id)
print("accessed details %s" %picture)

context = {
    "picture": picture
}

return render(request, "picture_details.html", context)
```

gallery_details.html

```
{% for picture in pictures %}
        <div class="img">
            <a href="{% url 'gallery:details' picture.id %}">
                <img src="{{ picture.picture_thumbnail.url }}" />
            </a>
            <div class="desc">{{ picture.description|truncatewords:5 }}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

When i try to run this i get an exception value:

```
Reverse for 'details' with arguments '(3,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['gallery/(?P<album_id>\\d+)/(?P<pic_id>\\d+)/$']
```

It should load page with single image, but it doesn't. Don't know why.

Comment: Would you expect it to match the second pattern in your `urlpatterns`? Have you tried removing the final slash `/` from that pattern?

Comment: Ok, i removed `/` from `urlpatterns` and now if i go to site http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/2/1 manually it works. But still, url http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/1/ doesn't work

Comment: Have you removed it from both `details` and `album_details`?

Comment: Yes, but now still same error.

Comment: Doesn't `'gallery:details'` require 2 arguments (album_id, pic_id), but you provide only one (`"{% url 'gallery:details' picture.id %}"`)?

Comment: In gallery_details.html added `<a href="{% url 'gallery:details' album.id picture.id %}">`. Also, in views.py added album_id argument `def details(request, album_id, pic_id)`. Now it opens http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/1/. But when i click on photo, only link changes, but nothing actually happens.

Comment: Does nothing happen or does it reload the page?

Comment: Nothing happens. Doesn't reaload page. Just url changes from http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/1/1/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/1/2/

Comment: I've undeleted my answer for the time being because Im still sure thats the problem if it is i'll expand on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to rearrange your urls so that the less specific one is first

```
url(r'^(?P<album_id>\d+)$', views.album_details, name='album_details'),
url(r'^(?P<album_id>\d+)/(?P<pic_id>\d+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
```

You will also note that I've modified the first regex to include the `$` character to indicate thats the end of the match

Comment: Not sure which one of these two things is the exact issue but it should fix the issue

Comment: Oh it works now, thank you! Ordering didn't affect anything but `$` actually does. `url(r'^(?P<album_id>\d+)/$', views.album_details,name='album_details'),` now works fine.

Comment: @Mažas -  The reason I said to order them is because django checks for regex matches in order, and then the $ makes it a more specific regex. Glad it helped